# LIKE Buttons from Facebook Using Open Graph Tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have a website that has movies and reviews. On a particular movie page, I have a movie title and a Facebook like button. I want this like button to use the Open Graph API. But beneath the movie, I have reviews that also have like buttons. I want these reviews to not use the graph API and just use the link to the review as the like.

Is this possible?

Comment: What is to «use the Open Graph API»?

Comment: i meant open graph tags to link the likes into facebook better

Comment: When someone clicks a like button, Facebook will read the Open Graph tags of the page at the button's `href` attribute. You can't avoid that.

Comment: yeah so for multiple like buttons, they'll all be the same, oh well

Comment: 10 like buttons with the same `href` attribute can be likened to 10 `<img>` tags with the same `src` attribute. Why don't you make your first like button have the current URL as its `href` attribute, and each review's like button have their respective review's URL as the `href`?

Comment: that is how its done now, was wondering how to get the open graph tags to be on the first one only

Comment: You will have to find a way to explain better what you want do do. Like buttons don't have Open Graph tags — web pages do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<meta property="og:title" content="Spaceballs"/> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId={{your app id}}";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div id="movie-info">
  <h1>Spaceballs</h1>
  <h3>Sci-Fi, Spoof, Comedy</h3>
  <div class="fb-like"></div>
</div>

<div>
  <div id="review-1">
    <div>The crappiest movie I ever saw.</div>
    <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/Spaceballs/Review/1"></div>
  </div>
<div id="review-2">
  <div>Some people just don't get Mel Brooks, but if you do this movie will likely cause stack overflows in your data processors.</div>
  <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://example.com/Spaceballs/Review/2"></div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your question, but just change the `href` attribute on the like buttons?